# How to control size of input in .input-group with .input-group-addon (Bootstrap3)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

A have a form in a table, and all my field sizes are fitting well. But I have one datefield that has an .input-group-addon, an that is making the size control not work very well. Is there a way to fix it?

I tried some ways to make a smaller input, but the addon stopped being attached:
http://jsfiddle.net/93MpC/1/

The code from Fiddle:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr class="form-group">
    <td><label class="field-label required-field">Name:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" required id="id_name" class="form-control">
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-group">
    <td><label class="field-label">Birthdate:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control datefield" id="id_dataNasc" name="dataNasc" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-group">
    <td><label class="field-label">Birthdate:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-group"><div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input class="form-control datefield" id="id_dataNasc" name="dataNasc" type="text"></div>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-group">
        <td><label class="field-label">Birthdate:</label></td>
        <td><div class="input-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-lg-2"><input class="form-control datefield" id="id_dataNasc" name="dataNasc" type="text"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proper HTML for this requires another level of nesting. More information can be found in the [input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios) documentation.

The `<td>` with your sized input and addon should look like this:

```
<td class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

The `.col-*` classes add padding left and right, so if that's a problem you can remove it with a little bit of CSS.

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't imagine I needed another input-group inside. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some somewhat cleaner HTML. I missed the doubly-nested `input-group`s - don't do that!

Answer (score 4):

Taken from your code, I added a class half to the parent div. Here's the css:

```
.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

And the HTML (almost the same):

```
<div class="input-group half"><!-- here is .half -->
  <input class="form-control datefield" id="id_dataNasc" name="dataNasc" type="text"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Edit** Or if you want to use col here's a different option:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">Birthdate:</div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control datefield" id="id_dataNasc" name="dataNasc" type="text"/>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://bootply.com/78312)

Comment: That works but doesn't use default Bootstrap classes. Bojangles solved it without adding external CSS, but thank anyways.

Comment: Didn't realise that wasn't an option. I've added another example using bootstrop columns only